# using Rails ActionCable to create a live chat but .scrollTop jQuery is not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, actioncable

In `javascripts/channels` I have this`messages.js` file with two functions - 1) for appending data to the view, clearing the form, and making sure that the div is scrolled down to display the most recently sent message, and 2) a helper for the message content.

The file looks like this:

```
App.messages = App.cable.subscriptions.create('MessagesChannel', {
 received: function(data) {
  $("#response").val("");
  $("#conversation-main").scrollTop($("#conversation-main")[0].scrollHeight);
  return $('#messages').append(this.renderMessage(data));
 },

 renderMessage: function(data) {
  return "<div class='message'><div><strong>" + data.user + ":</strong> " + data.body + "</div><div class='date'>" + data.time + "</div></div>"
 }
});
```

My problem is that the message is being appended, but the `scrollTop` is not being executed. Why is this? Additionally - if I change this file to `js.erb` and use the `simple_format` helper, the appending is prevented entirely. The data is still persisted and the websockets subscription is sent and received, but the view does not update with the new message appended to the bottom of the div. Should I define this behavior elsewhere? The view looks like this:

```
<div class="column">
 <div class="conversation" id="conversation-main">
  <div id="conversation-body" data-conversation-id="<%= @conversation.id %>">
   <div id="messages">
    <% @messages.each do |message| %>
     <% if message.body %>
      <%= render "message", message: message %>
     <% end %>
    <% end %>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="column">
 <div class="ui form"> 
  <%= form_for [@conversation, @message], remote: true do |f| %>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :message %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: "Your message", id:"response" %>
   </div>
   <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  <% end %>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to rule this out: open the console in chrome inspector and type $("#response").length or $("#conversation-main").length and see if you get a 1 or 2 in response. If  you get a 2 change the $("#conversation-main") and $("#response") to a class instead as id's need to be unique.

Comment: i get a 1 for  both

Comment: `return` is exiting the function before the line where `scrollTop` is.

Comment: @Gerry unfortunately, putting `scrollTop` above that does nothing different

Comment: That's because now the scroll happens _before_ the append. Its not that simple to autoscroll, but you can find a way to do it [here](https://www.learnenough.com/action-cable-tutorial#sec-auto_scroll).

Comment: Oh wow this link is very helpful! Thank you Gerry.

Comment: Hope it helps. When you solve it, please post your solution (i.e. answer your own question) to help other devs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending the message, after you `scrollTop`. Try doing

```
App.messages = App.cable.subscriptions.create('MessagesChannel', {
 received: function(data) {
  $("#response").val("");
  $('#messages').append(this.renderMessage(data));
  $("#conversation-main").scrollTop($("#conversation-main")[0].scrollHeight);
 },

 renderMessage: function(data) {
  return "<div class='message'><div><strong>" + data.user + ":</strong> " + data.body + "</div><div class='date'>" + data.time + "</div></div>"
 }
});
```

I don't believe you need to return out of the first function. But you definitely need to know the height of the div including the newest message in order to see the scroll to the end of the div after message entry.

Comment: this works! do you have any idea why the embedded ruby in the js file prevents the async js from appending? i'm trying to use `simple_format(data.body)` in the `renderMessage` function, but it interferes.

Comment: Not sure exactly from context, feel free to post more code though. And accept answer so others can find this!

Comment: ^ you probably just have to re-interpolate your ruby in the js.erb file `$('#messages').append(<%= ruby_simple_format_blah(data) %>)`

Comment: the problem is something with the fact that `data` doesn't work inside ruby, but does work in js. `<%= simple_format(data.body) %>` results in an `undefined local variable or method 'data'`, but `data.body` goes through.

Comment: ah `data` is still javascript.. simple answer is you cannot. I recommend formatting that data response in the Rails controller before it gets passed to the view.

Comment: if you see the question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54583221/how-to-use-ruby-in-a-js-file/54655687#54655687), that is what i'm doing....i think. my variable (`@message`) is assigned in the `#create` action, and then used inside an Action Cable broadcast. presumably i should be able to interpolate `<%= simple_format(@message.body) %>` in a string, but...that just results in `undefined method 'body' for nil:NilClass`. also i'm not sure if this matters or not, but the js file is in `app/assets/javascripts`, not the view folder