# how to use ruby in a js assets file? (undefined method 'body')

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I'm following [this tutorial](https://blog.heroku.com/real_time_rails_implementing_websockets_in_rails_5_with_action_cable) and having a problem where using ruby in an ActionCable file causes an `undefined method 'body'` error. How can I use ruby in this file? I want the data that's submitted over Action Cable to be properly formatted when it is appended, and I cannot do that with plain js. This is my `app/assets/js/channels/messages.js.erb` file:

```
App.messages = App.cable.subscriptions.create('MessagesChannel', {
 received: function(data) {
  $("#response").val("");
  $('#messages').append(this.render_message(data));
  $("#conversation-main").scrollTop($("#conversation-main")[0].scrollHeight);
 },

 render_message: function(data) {
  return "<div class='message'><div><strong>" + data.user + ":</strong> <%= simple_format(@message.body) %></div><div class='date'><%= readable_datetime(@message.created_at) %></div></div>"
 }
});
```

I can't do `simple_format(data.body)` since that variable is js. Here's the `#create` action in my messages controller:

```
def create
    @message = @conversation.messages.new(message_params)
    @message.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
        if @message.save
            ActionCable.server.broadcast 'messages',
                body: @message.body,
                user: @message.user.username,
                time: @message.created_at
            head :ok
        end
    end
end
```

I have `@message` defined in the action, and it should be passed onto the js.erb file. But it's not. Why?

Comment: If you're using ERB then you must inline with `<%= ... %>` or it will not run any Ruby code at all.

Comment: That makes so much sense. I thought the `<%= %>` was for html files only. This solution gives rise to a new problem though: the `data` variable is found outside the erb, but not inside. I get an `undefined local variable or method`.

Comment: The ERB directives are for *text* files of any sort, of which JavaScript, HTML, CSS, and even JSON or CSV all qualify. We live in a largely text-based world these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `messages.js.erb` is in `assets` folder and ERB will run only once at assets compilation time.

Easier is to format before broadcasting while still in ruby controller context:

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast 'messages',
            body: helpers.simple_format(@message.body),
            user: @message.user.username,
            time: @message.created_at
```

Comment: oh right *facepalm* you can use helpers inside the controller by calling `helpers.helper_name`. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

When you have Ruby code that you want to run inside any of your .erb files, you must use the `<% ... %>` or `<%= ... %>` notation surrounding the Ruby text. The `=` in `<%= ... %>` is for outputting the code.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: That makes so much sense. I thought the <%= %> was for html files only. This solution gives rise to a new problem though: the data variable is found outside the erb, but not inside. I get an `undefined local variable or method 'data'` error.

Comment: I think it might also be worth pointing out that this code runs from the `app/assets/javascripts` file, not the controller.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `data` to be present here, it'll have to be an instance variable like `@data` that's assigned in the controller in order to be present when the view gets rendered.

From there you can do anything you want in "Ruby mode" engaged using:

```
render_message: function(data) {
  return "<div class='message'><div><strong><%= @data.user %>:</strong> <%= simple_format(@data.body) %></div><div class='date'><%= readable_datetime(@data.time) %></div></div>"
}
```

Or something approximately like that.

Remember that ERB substitutions are applied once and only once *before* the content is forwarded to the client for processing. There's no way to run Ruby after the output is rendered.

Comment: I forgot to include my controller action in the above code (see edit #3), but that is pretty much what I have been doing. I have a `@message` defined inside `#create` but outside the `ActionCable.server.broadcast`. Inside the broadcast message are variables for `body`, `user`, and `time`.  Those variables work in js, but not in ruby. Using `@message.body` in the `js.erb` file is no different.